# SQL server not executing multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to create a table with around 1,000 columns by joining 25 tables and selecting the columns I need out of each table.

After running the query for 24 hours I noticed that "nothing" is happening: The memory usage doesn't increase, and there is no empty table being created as soon as the query kicks off, or after 24 hours.

I am accustomed to seeing an empty table being created as soon as a query kicks off, and this table being populated once the query is finished.

I've restarted SQL server as well as the server itself, and re-executed the query a number of times and there's no change. It's as if it decides it's just not gonna do it. Any ideas as to why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: 1000 columns...But why?

Comment: Sounds crazy I know. We're using these columns as features in a random forest, and it's also a client requirement to submit the data in this format...

Comment: Did you think about the fact that joining 25 tables could take for ever? so the query won't finish in decades?

Comment: add `WHERE 1=2` and see if an empty table gets created immediately

Comment: Well, if that's the case then this is obviously not practical. But I still expect it to start the execution?

Comment: Thanks @raj, I tried that and the empty table gets created, what does this mean?

Comment: This means that your query works fine. It is the joins that is causing an issue. Unless we are able to see your code, table and index structures, it is going to be hard to help. You might want to break it into smaller result sets, by joining 5 tables and putting the results into temp tables and then subsequently joining those temp tables

Comment: Start with a small amount of joins, obviously, increasing one by one to see where performance will degrade significantly.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Raj. Unfortunately I can't share the exact code/tables due to data sensitivity issues. The query is very straightforward though. I will use your suggestion of consecutive queries and give feedback, prob only tomorrow :)

Comment: Alternately, you can also set a limit to the result set by using `SET ROWCOUNT` and then run the query iteratively

Comment: Cool I'll give that a go too, thanks @Raj